# Revit API add parameter to multiple categories

Tags: c#, revit-api

I am trying to add a shared parameter to a specific category and I succeded. However, when I tried to implement the code in a for loop to create the parameter in multiple categories I fail.
the first code is for the single category and it works fine.

```
UIDocument uidoc = this.Application.ActiveUIDocument;
Document doc = uidoc.Document;
            
        
            
String modulePath = doc.PathName;
String tit = doc.Title;
            
String paramFile = modulePath.Substring(0,modulePath.Length-47) + "\\addParameterTest.txt";
            

 if (File.Exists(paramFile))
          {
              File.Delete(paramFile);
          }

FileStream fs = File.Create(paramFile);
fs.Close();
            
this.Application.Application.SharedParametersFilename = paramFile;
                    
DefinitionFile parafile = this.Application.Application.OpenSharedParameterFile();
                    
                
            
ExternalDefinitionCreationOptions externalDefinitionCreationOptions = new ExternalDefinitionCreationOptions("New Parameter", ParameterType.Text);
    
DefinitionGroup apiGroup = parafile.Groups.Create("Test");
Definition newSharedParamDef = apiGroup.Definitions.Create(externalDefinitionCreationOptions);
            
      
            

            
            
Category columnCat = doc.Settings.Categories.get_Item(BuiltInCategory.OST_StructuralColumns);
            
CategorySet categories = this.Application.Application.Create.NewCategorySet();
InstanceBinding binding = this.Application.Application.Create.NewInstanceBinding(categories);
if (columnCat.AllowsBoundParameters) {
using (Transaction trn = new Transaction(doc,"add parameter")) {
           trn.Start();
       categories.Insert(columnCat);
    doc.ParameterBindings.Insert(newSharedParamDef, binding);
    trn.Commit();
            }
            }
```

The second code is for the for loop

```
            UIDocument uidoc = this.Application.ActiveUIDocument;
            Document doc = uidoc.Document;
            
        
            
            String modulePath = doc.PathName;
            String tit = doc.Title;
            
            String paramFile = modulePath.Substring(0,modulePath.Length-47) + "\\addParameterTest.txt";
            

       `     if (File.Exists(paramFile))
                {
                    File.Delete(paramFile);
                }

            FileStream fs = File.Create(paramFile);
            fs.Close();
            
            this.Application.Application.SharedParametersFilename = paramFile;
                    
            DefinitionFil`e parafile = this.Application.Application.OpenSharedParameterFile();
                    
                
            
ExternalDefinitionCreationOptions externalDefinitionCreationOptions = new ExternalDefinitionCreationOptions("New Parameter", ParameterType.Text);
    
DefinitionGroup apiGroup = parafile.Groups.Create("Test");
            Definition newSharedParamDef = apiGroup.Definitions.Create(externalDefinitionCreationOptions);
            
      
Categories cat = doc.Settings.Categories;

CategorySet categories = this.Application.Application.Create.NewCategorySet();

InstanceBinding binding = this.Application.Application.Create.NewInstanceBinding(categories);

            using (Transaction trn = new Transaction(doc,"add parameter")) {

            
                    trn.Start();
            foreach (Category element in cat) {
                
                if (element.AllowsBoundParameters)
                {
                    
         


                    categories.Insert(element);
                    doc.ParameterBindings.Insert(newSharedParamDef, binding);
               
                }
            }   
             trn.Commit();
            }
```

I expect to add a parameter for each instance of a category for example wall, column, etc....

Comment: How does it fail? What happens instead of what you expect?

Comment: there is no error but nothing happens (no parameter is added). Something silly is missing in the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `CategorySet` is a set, a collection of categories, you can add all the required ones to the set up front, before binding.

Here is a sample on [adding a category to an existing shared parameter binding](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2012/04/adding-a-category-to-a-shared-parameter-binding.html).

Here is some code that I like for [creation of shared parameters](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2013/12/driving-cnc-fabrication-and-shared-parameters.html). It binds three parameters to one single category, but I think you could just add as many categories as you like to the `CategorySet`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It helped to figure out the solution. The issue is getting the binding out of the for loop! Silly me!

Comment: Congratulations on solving! Glad I could help.